# CustomView setting size

Tags: objective-c, macos

I'm trying to set CustomView size, CustomView is in NSWindow. The problem is that when the window resizes, CustomView resizes with the window. Any ideas how to set CustomView size and make it not resizable?

Answer (score 0):

check under the size inspector on the right pane in xcode and check if the view has any autosizing constraints that are making it do that.

Comment: Autoresizes subviews is unchecked and it has no autosizing constrains declared im thinking that it has something to do with this line of code: - (void)viewBoundsDidChange:(NSRect)bounds
{
    NSLog(@"resizeing");
    if ((self.imageAccumulator != nil) && (CGRectEqualToRect (*(CGRect *)&bounds, [self.imageAccumulator extent]))) {
        return;
    }

Comment: if i delete this line "&& (CGRectEqualToRect (*(CGRect *)&bounds, [self.imageAccumulator extent])))" my Custom view get the size from windows frame and stays in that size even if i resize window but i cant set Custom view size by my self with NSRect or CGRect.